# Where can I find the original release notes for JUnit 4.8 to 4.8.2?

Tags: java, junit, documentation

I have some different enviroments using different versions of JUnit 4.8. I wanted to have a look at the release notes to see what's different in those versions. But they aren't available anymore where they were [originally published](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/doc/ReleaseNotes4.8.2.html). Has someone another link for me or can someone post a copy of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the release notes here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/tree/master/doc

Comment: Thanks, I really should have looked in the source control first.